# count stars in swiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

```
import SwiftUI

struct RatingStars: View {
    @State var starState : Int
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack{
            ForEach(0..<starState){ index in
                Button{
                    self.starState = index
                } label :{
                    Text("★")
                        .font(.system(size: 30))
                }
            }
            ForEach(0..<5-starState){ index in
                Button{
                    self.starState = index
                } label :{
                    Text("☆")
                        .font(.system(size: 30))
                }
            }
            
        }.padding()
        
    }
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TYy9Q.png)

I am implementing a ui where two stars are filled when the second star is pressed.

I am expecting the view to be redrawn when the starState variable changes.

Now my code doesn't change much when I press the star. What's the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using `ForEach` you need to provide objects that are identifiable. In your case you can use the integer itself so `ForEach(0..<starState)` becomes `ForEach(0..<starState, id: \.self)`.

PS: You have another problem: you use separate `ForEach`s which will provide you with different indexes. You can resolve this by merging them into one like this:

```
ForEach(0..<5, id: \.self) { index in
    Button {
        self.starState = index
    } label: {
        let star = index <= starState ? "★" : "☆"
        Text(star)
            .font(.system(size: 30))
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**

As @Leo Dabus mentioned my example uses indexes and not the number of stars when initializing the view. To fix that you simply need to modify the range to `1...5`. So your code will look like this:

```
import SwiftUI

struct RatingStars: View {
    
    @State var starState: Int

    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            ForEach(1...5, id: \.self) { index in
                Button {
                    self.starState = index
                } label: {
                    let star = index <= starState ? "★" : "☆"
                    Text(star)
                        .font(.system(size: 30))
                }
            }
        }.padding()
    }
    
}
```

Comment: The only issue with this approach is the initial value. You should use `self.starState = index + 1` and  `index < starState`

Comment: Another issue with the approach is that clicking on a star will only turn it on. You are better off using a struct that knows its own state of on or off, so that taping a star switches that particular star. Taking in to account that it must be the marginal star.

Comment: @Yrb this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71225223/2303865) solves both issues

Comment: @Yrb added toggle functionality as well if the user clicks again at the current star selected

Comment: @LeoDabus You are just suggesting a different approach on handling the data. My suggestion doesn't have a problem with initial value. I do agree that it isn't the best but the question was why the OP's code doesn't work.

Comment: @spasbil Can you post a project sample that I can test it? When I tried your code here when using 2 to stars it would display 3 stars the creating the view. After clicking any star it would show the correct result. Not sure why.  Anyway I've posted the solution to the initial state issue.

Comment: @LeoDabus That was the idea, to pass the index, but you can always just change the range to `1...5` and it will behave as you expected, just will suggest to rename the variable from `starState` to `starCount` to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 0):

Besides the lack of an identifier in your ForEach as already mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71223866/2303865) you can simply add a long press gesture to your text view and onChange set your starState to `index + 1`. When setting your text string you can use a ternary operator as suggested by @spasbil but use less then to fix the initial state issue of his post:

```
ForEach(0..<5, id: \.self) { index in
    Text(index < starState ? "★" : "☆")
        .font(.system(size: 30))
        .gesture(LongPressGesture().onChanged { _ in 
            starState = index + 1 
        })
}
```

edit/update:

If you would like to be able to toggle the current star as well:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var starState : Int
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            ForEach(0..<5, id: \.self) { index in
                Text(index < starState ? "★" : "☆")
                    .font(.system(size: 30))
                    .gesture(LongPressGesture().onChanged { _ in
                        starState = index + 1 == starState ? starState - 1 : index + 1
                })
            }
        }.padding()
    }
}
```

---

```
struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView(starState: 1)
    }
}
```

Comment: It may be a little less confusing as `starState = starState == index ? starState - 1 :  index`. Same result, less `+ 1s`.

Comment: @Yrb That wouldn't work as it is. I had many variations. I could change the ForEach range to `1..<6` as well to make it clearer. I just threw the first one that came to my mind to keep the same range.

Comment: I posted what I had when I commented on the first answer. Take it for a test drive.

Comment: @Yrb that wouldn't fix the initial value. You would need to change the range as well.  `1..<6`, `index <= starState ? "★" : "☆"`, and `starState = index == starState ? starState - 1 : index`

Comment: Well, it seems to work fine in testing...from 0 to 5 stars

Comment: @Yrb for me it adds a star to the initial value. If I choose value 1 it would show two stars at launch

Comment: You have to add an `=` to your test in `Text(index <= starState ? "★" : "☆")`

Comment: Yes I did as well [starsRatingInitialIssue](https://www.dropbox.com/s/g08l6k8c9trupgy/starsRatingInitialIssue.png?dl=1)